# Day wise Rolling 30 day uniques user count bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to generate a day on day rolling 30 days unique count using this query but the problem is running this query day on the day I need aug full month  rolling 30 days day on day count in one script pls help

```
-----------------------------------------
SELECT  max(date),count(DISTINCT user_id) as MAU
FROM user_data  
WHERE date between DATE_SUB('2020-08-31' ,INTERVAL  29 DAY) and '2020-08-31';
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question. What is the problem with the current query?

Comment: It won't answer your question but shouldn't that be a 30 day interval?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . No, because the current day is included.  The current days plus 29 previous days account for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't support rolling windows for `count(distinct)`.  So, one approach is a brute force method:

```
select dte,
       (select count(distinct ud.user_id)
        from user_data ud
        where ud.date between DATE_SUB(dte, INTERVAL 29 DAY) and dte
       ) as num_users
from unnest(generate_date_array(date('2020-08-01'), date('2020-08-31'))) dte
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon approach works great.
If you need to calculate more numbers - Cross join the data.

```
SELECT 
  date_gen,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ud.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(date_gen ,INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND date_gen,ud.user_id,NULL)) as MAU
FROM 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB('2020-08-31' ,INTERVAL 29 DAY), date('2020-08-31'))) date_gen,
  (SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2020-08-31' ,INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND '2020-08-31') AS ud
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

With SET and DECLARE you can get rid of replacing the 'DATE' multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM t.users AS id) AS MAU
FROM (
  SELECT date, ARRAY_AGG(user_id) OVER(mau_win) users
  FROM `project.dataset.user_data`  
  WINDOW mau_win AS (
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 29 FOLLOWING
  )
) t
```

Above assumes you have entries in `project.dataset.user_data` table for all days in time period of your interest

If this is not a case, and you actually have some gaps in your data  - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM t.users AS id) AS MAU
FROM (
  SELECT date, ARRAY_AGG(user_id) OVER(mau_win) users
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-08-01', '2020-08-31')) AS date
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.user_data`  
  USING(date)
  WINDOW mau_win AS (
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 29 FOLLOWING
  )
) t
```