# Counting unique column values in a rolling N day window in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I have data (results of a subquery or base data) that looks like below:

[image]

And I am trying to create two new columns to it such that they count the distinct values under CLASS_DESC column in a 60 day rolling window. Below is the desired output:

[image]

I tried below code to generate the desired output but it is not producing the correct results. Further I looked at few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658874/count-unique-ids-in-a-rolling-time-frame/47659590#47659590) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710129/day-wise-rolling-30-day-uniques-user-count-bigquery) but unable to translate them to my problem.

```
WITH AnchorSupportTxns AS (
---Base Table
),
AnchorSupportCounts AS (
SELECT
HH_ID,
SLS_DT,
CLASS_TYPE,
COUNTIF(CLASS_TYPE = 'ANCHOR') OVER (PARTITION BY HH_ID ORDER BY SLS_DT ASC ROWS BETWEEN 59 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS COUNT_UNIQUE_ANCHOR_LAST_60D,
COUNTIF(CLASS_TYPE = 'SUPPORT') OVER (PARTITION BY HH_ID ORDER BY SLS_DT ASC ROWS BETWEEN 59 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS COUNT_UNIQUE_SUPPORT_LAST_60D
FROM AnchorSupportTxns
)
SELECT
D.*,
ASCL.COUNT_UNIQUE_ANCHOR_LAST_60D,
ASCL.COUNT_UNIQUE_SUPPORT_LAST_60D
FROM AnchorSupportTxns AS D
JOIN AnchorSupportCounts AS ASCL
ON D.HH_ID = ASCL.HH_ID 
AND D.SLS_DT = ASCL.SLS_DT 
AND D.CLASS_TYPE = ASCL.CLASS_TYPE;
```

Wrong output from the above query:

[image]

I feel like I am close but also can't figure out how to do the distinct count instead of absolute count and also number of rows in the output is more than the desired. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Scott Grammilo, Have you tried using the [Ranking Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-ranking-functions/) ? Also another option is, you can try using the `Partition by `on grouping the 3 columns `HH_ID` , `SLS_DT` and `CLASS_TYPE` , that might help you getting the expected output.